# Meteor and Mongo, reducing the bandwidth used?

Tags: mongodb, meteor

1. MongoDB is a document-oriented database.
2. Meteor pub/sub/call communicates the data through JSON.
3. JSON uses a key–value pair style formalism.
4. This means each time data is sent, the 'key' are sent with the value.

   `length(json sent) = length(attributes values) * length(attributes names) * Xdoc`

Let's simplify and say that in average keys and values have the same length.

```
length(json sent) = 2 x length(attributes values) * Xdoc
```

This means that half of the data (and I am skipping the =/,/{,} ) is redundant.

Document-based is not table-sql-like and attributes of a same collection may totally differ.

**But does that really make no sense to try to optimize this ?**

For instance building a key dictionary, using binary or optimizing size as google protocol buffer would ?

Why this question ? Because I have 10MB collections that the client needs, and it's getting slow, if course I would optimize with pagination and filtering keys, but I want to know :)

-- A meteor/mongo noob.

PS: I am not looking for a walkthrough, but for an explanation of why no optimisation could be done on the json data length sent.

Comment: Does every client really need the entirety of a 10MB collection? Reducing the number of keys sent can be a big help, as well as reducing the set of documents requested to be only those that are really needed. In some cases you only need the primary key and a couple values for each document at first, then all the keys for a document when an object is clicked on or hovered over (the detail view).

Answer (score 0):

The answer is that the actual amount of bytes transferred is very seldom an issue. 10M is not a lot of data unless you have some limitations on your network.

Transferring 10M in one, or a few frames (as in request/response round-trips) is no problem. But if you're doing it in 10000 frames with 1k per frame it will take lots of ms.

And then this data is stored (expanded) client side, most often several times with additional overhead, eating a lot of RAM and making the app slow too.

So unless you have some funny corner case, working on keeping the number of request/responses down and limiting the amount of copying of the data that goes on in your client code will have a significantly larger impact than worrying about sending 10M bytes over the wire.